# Run Redis service as non-root user

Tags: redis

I have installed it in RHEL 7 and configured it a bit. 
It is up and running as a root.

I am trying to run Redis Service as non-root user.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: please add more details

Answer (score 3):

If the user and group “redis” has not been created,please create it.

```
useradd redis
```

Then change the owner of the file named "redis-server" and "redis-cli"(Actually,I advice chang all the files about redis but I do not know the path you installed).

```
chown redis. "your path"
```

create the script like this

```
vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service
```

Write the contents

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network.target
[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
Type=forking
ExecStart="the absolute path of redis-server" "ths absolute path of redis.conf"
ExecStop="the absolute path of redis-cli" shutdown
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then you can use the following codes

```
systemctl status redis
systemctl start redis //start the service
sysyemctl stop redis //stop the service
systemctl enable redia //start the service when system boot
```

I also paste the config in my machine and it works well for me
[image]

Wish this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For those who use `docker`, you can build your own redis image with non-root user as the following:

```
FROM redis:6.0.10-alpine

# Create the home directory for the new non-root user.
RUN mkdir -p /home/nonroot
# Create an non-root user so our program doesn't run as root.
RUN adduser -S -h /home/nonroot nonroot
VOLUME /home/nonroot/tmp

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=10s --start-period=30s --retries=3 \
  CMD redis-cli ping

USER nonroot

EXPOSE 6379
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably also add the working directory to the service since redis does not seem to change to that on its own (at least on my configuration):

```
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/redis
```